# Django ImageField not deleted if default is set

Tags: python, django

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    watermark_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, default=settings.WATERMARK_DEFAULT)
```

When I try to empty the field in the admin clicking on its checkbox, file is not deleted unless i remove default attribute from model! Why?

Answer (score 1):

The default attribute in a model field has exactly that purpose: 
If an object has no watermark_image attribute use the default image. 
Why is this important? 
Imagine if you have a field that cannot be blank, because it would otherwise lead to a database inconsistency.

For example if you would have a User model that has a profile_picture field.

When looping through a list of users in a list like this:

```
[user.profile_picture for user in User.objects.all()]
```

When you have a default value set on the model level for the profile_picture attribute you do not have to worry about this code. If you would not have that default value this code could raise an AttributeError for users that have no profile_picture set.

Therefore it is impossible to delete an attribute that has a default value set in the admin, because it would eliminate the purpose of the default keyword argument in the model attribute.

Comment: This behaviour is what i need, but the problem is that when I delete file and I click on 'save', the image is not replaced by default value

Comment: remove blank=True, null=True from the model attribute because those fields allow empty entries on that attribute, does that work?

Comment: I'm trying but migrate return this error:

django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(100)

Comment: if this just a development database and data loss is no problem, try to delete the watermark_image field from the model, make the migrations and then redeclare the field without the blank=True, null=True values. Be careful deleting this attribute from the model will delete all references to images saved there in existing models.